# Groupby, value counts and calculate percentage in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have groupby `state`, value counts `industry` of a dataframe.

```
df.loc[df['state'].isin(['Alabama','Arizona'])].groupby(df['state'])['industry'].value_counts(sort = True)
```

Out:

```
state    industry                              
Alabama  Financial Services                        224
         Education                                   7
         Healthcare, Pharmaceuticals, & Biotech      5
         Business Services                           2
         Other                                       2
         Retail                                      2
         Government                                  1
         Manufacturing                               1
         Transportation & Storage                    1
Arizona  Healthcare, Pharmaceuticals, & Biotech     19
         Other                                      13
         Education                                   5
         Retail                                      5
         Transportation & Storage                    5
         Manufacturing                               4
         Travel, Recreation, and Leisure             4
         Consumer Services                           3
         Energy & Utilities                          2
         Financial Services                          2
         Government                                  2
         Business Services                           1
         Computers & Electronics                     1
         Software & Internet                         1
Name: industry, dtype: int64
```

Now I would like to go further, get percentage of value counts, for example, for `Alabama`, I want to know the percentage of `Financial Services`, which is calculated by `224/ (224 + 7 + ... + 1)`, etc.

How could I do that by using new code or modify the code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `normalize`

```
df.loc[df['state'].isin(['Alabama','Arizona'])].groupby(df['state'])['industry'].value_counts(sort = True, normalize=True)
```